# Converting 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>'

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections, implicit-conversion

I have a Collection, I'm trying to use the Distinct method to remove duplicates.

```
public static Collection<MediaInfo> imagePlaylist

imagePlaylist = imagePlaylist.Distinct(new API.MediaInfoComparer());
```

I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

imagePlaylist used to be a List (i could use .ToList()), but to comply with "CA1002  Do not expose generic lists" I want to convert the List to a Collection.

-Thanks

Comment: Does your collection need to expose Add and Remove to the public? Do you need to have random access via an index? If not, you could simply expose `imagePlaylist` as `IEnumerable<MediaInfo>` for a readonly sequence.

Comment: @anthonyPegram Those methods need to be exposed, using IEnumerable isnt an option in this case

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you can do is, first convert the `IEnumrable` to generic list and then use this list to create a new `Collection` using the parametrized constructor of `Collection` class.

```
public static Collection<MediaInfo> imagePlaylist

imagePlaylist = new Collection<MediaInfo>
                    (
                       imagePlaylist
                      .Distinct(new API.MediaInfoComparer())
                      .ToList()
                    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a little extension method for this:

```
public static class CollectionUtils
{
    public static Collection<T> ToCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        return new Collection<T>(data.ToList());
    }
}
```

So you can then do the conversion inline & reuse the utility throughout your solution:

```
imagePlaylist.Distinct(new API.MediaInfoComparer()).ToCollection();
```